# i get more rows than there are after the operation, in 2 different operations / Half Answered

Tags: python, list, for-loop, data-cleaning

up till this function everything is fine, i get 4999 rows, that's the amount i got. Can you check the code down below, where do i make mistakes that i end up having **5095 instead of 4999** and in the second function i have 5032 instead of 4999 instances

I have to get no more than 4999.
Any help is appreciated

```
a=[]
for i in matches:
    a.append([i for i in list(dict.fromkeys(i))])
print(len(a))
print ((a))
```

result:

```
4999
[['23-year-old'], [' '], ['42 years old'], ['-year-old']..]
```

can the **-year-old** be a problem in here?

**Now here i face the problem**

```
t=[]
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        p=len(j)
        if p>1:
            r=j.replace('-', ' ').split(' ')
#             print(r)
            t+=[s for s in r if s.isdigit()]
        else:
            t+=['']
print(len(t))
print(t)
```

output:

```
5095 #This should be 4999
['23', '', '42', '', '', '30', '31', ''...]
```

I do have also the same issue with the list of the gender? i end up having **5032**

*This part is not answered yet*

```
import re

fil = data['transcription']
print(fil)

gender_aux = []
for i in fil:

    try:
        gender = re.findall("female|gentleman|woman|lady|man|male|girl|boy|she|he", i) or [" "]
    except:
        gender_aux.append(' ')
#         pass

    gender_dict = {"male": ["gentleman", "man", "male", "boy",'he'],
               "female": ["lady","female", "woman", "girl",'she']}

    for g in gender:
        if g in gender_dict['male']:
            gender_aux.append('male')
            break
        elif g in gender_dict['female']:
            gender_aux.append('female')
            break
        else:
            gender_aux+=[' ']
            break
print(len(gender_aux))            
print(gender_aux)
```

output:

```
5032 #this should be 4999
['female', 'male', 'male', ' ',
```

Comment: My guess is this line `[s for s in r if s.isdigit()]` sometimes returns more than one element.

Comment: @Sri, how can i handle it then? :/, i have to put this list as another column in a dataframe, and hence being more than 4999 it doesnt allow me, it raises error!

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what `a` actually looks like. I have the feeling there is an element like `['23 years old 24']

Comment: @Sri, is there any chance to help me, if i share the code/file with you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming there are no decimal values in your dataset, and that each list item will only contain one string, one number per string.**

If all you're after a list containing the integer values of everyone's ages, starting from your completed list `a`, you can simply

```
import re
t = [re.findall(r'\d+', item[0])[0] for item in a if re.findall(r'\d+', item[0])]
```

This list comprehension accomplishes a few things.

Firstly, because your `a` list is a list of single item lists, as we iterate through each item, we obtain the value of the first (and only) item in the list using `item[0]`. We then perform a regex operation (hence `import re`) on this item, with the search pattern `r'\d+'` which extracts only the integer values from each string (You can check out https://regex101.com/ to play around with regex patterns to better understand how they work).

Because `re.findall` returns a list of matches, and because it seems each string in your dataset will only contain one match (at most), we simply take the [0] index of the resulting list as our chosen value. Where there are no matches, `re.findall` returns an empty list.  Because empty lists evaluate to false, the `if` statement in our list comprehension will prevent index errors on strings where there are no numbers to be extracted.

Using your example, the resulting `t` array would be as follows:

```
['23', '42']
```

Note that the empty strings are not included in the final list.  If you wanted to include them, you could simply add an else condition to our if statement as follows:

```
t = [re.findall(r'\d+', item[0])[0] if re.findall(r'\d+', item[0]) else '' for item in a]
```

this would result in

```
['23', '', '42', '', '']
```

Lastly, if you wanted to convert each number (currently strings) to integer values, you could instead write:

```
t = [int(re.findall(r'\d+', item[0])[0]) if re.findall(r'\d+', item[0]) else '' for item in a]
```

which finally, would result in:

```
[23, '', 42, '', '']
```

Of course, this all assumes there are no decimal values in your dataset, and that each list item will only contain one string, with each string only containing one desired number.

For example, our `re.findall` with the string "I am 42 years old, and my son is 16", would return ['42', '16'], and because we only return the first item of the list, the final list would not include '16'.  Keep this in mind.

Because we aren't creating any additional items (e.g. by using `str.split()`), we can be sure the resulting list consists of the same number of elements (so long as we use the variant with the `else ''` statement).  If we use the first variant, the resulting list will contain only as many elements as there are elements in `a` containing numbers.

Comment: can you also help me with a very similar problem, i will update the question and you can see it, please?

Comment: can you please check the second part of the question please?